# isalpha() returning non-zero value for float/integer input

Tags: c, validation, error-checking

I am doing some error checking for my program in C, and am currently testing to make sure that input data point are `float`/`int` (essentially not characters)

For this purpose I am using the `isalpha` function. It works for all numbers under 100, but if I input a value of 100 it will return 1024 instead of 0. Any particular reason this happens, or would you know a better way to error check this?

```
if ((isalpha(T1) != 0) || (isalpha(T2) != 0) || (isalpha(T3) != 0)
|| (isalpha(X1) != 0) || (isalpha(X2) != 0) || (isalpha(X3) != 0))
{
    error checking statements
}
else
{
    Calculations
}
```

Comment: What types are `T1`,`X1`, `T2`, etc?  What are the values of those variables?

Comment: All of the variables are of type float for the input. T1 = 1, X1 = 5, T2 = 1.5, X2 = 20, T3 = 2. All those values return a 0 for isalpha

Comment: @user3390610 I edited my answer appropriately to suit `float` variables.

Comment: "It works for all numbers under 100" I suspect there are over `power(2,31)` `float` under 100.  They all work?

Comment: `isalpha()` returns whether the value passed corresponds to an ASCII value for an alphabet character. That is to say, it returns 0 if the value passed is not in the ranges `'a' - 'z', 'A' - 'Z'`. or decimal 65-90, 97-122.

Comment: explain "return 1024" ? There is no `return` in your code and all expressions evaluate to `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you pass a float to `isalpha`? What's the point storing a character in a float and checking it?

The declaration for `isalpha` is `int isalpha ( int c );`, so if you pass a float to it, the float will be **truncated to `int`**, making it produce a wrong result. Try inputting 99.5 or something like that and see

More importantly, `isalpha` only works with a char value or EOF, other values will invoke undefined behavior

> The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and is not equal to EOF.
>
> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha

This is essentially an XY problem. `isalpha` is not a way to validate input values. You need to get the input as string and check whether it fits your condition or not